# Does select top 10 * from tablename give same result every time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to know that Does select top 10 * from tablename give same result every time?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Even a table with PK clustered index is not guaranteed to return the same top x without an order by.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "same result". If you've defined the result it produces as "(up to) 10 rows that currently exist within `tablename`." then yes, it produces the same result. If, on the other hand, you're asking if it will always return the *same* 10 rows, then existing answers cover that.

Answer (score 5):

No.  The result set is *unordered* unless you specify an `order by` clause.  Even then, the `order by` needs to be stable, meaning that the keys have no ties (you accomplish this by putting the primary key as the last keys for the ordering).

There are several reason why results might differ.  Obviously, the underlying data might change, but I am guessing that is not the gist of your question.

The primary reason is on a multi-threaded machine, where different threads are reading the data.  Which thread returns the data is indeterminate, so you don't know what the first ten rows will be (without an `order by`).

SQL itself does not guarantee that tables are read in order for processing queries.  However, in practice, I do think that SQL Server does read the pages in order.

Answer (score 1):

No. It varies when new data are added. Also you should always use ORDER BY Clause explicitly if you use TOP operator

Comment: I have 100 fixed records and I don't want to use Order by clause .Then will it give same result when I execute Query