# How to select a fixed number of random rows based on a repeatable seeding?

Tags: sql, sql-server, random-seed

I'm struggling on how can I fix, for example, 5 random rows of my table in SQL. But I need to be able to repeatable retrieve the same 5 rows every time I run the code with a given seed.

I tried to use

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

But I didn't get the same sample each time that I run the code.

Any idea on how can I do that?

Comment: See this post on the subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406763/does-select-top-10-from-tablename-give-same-result-every-time

Comment: If you always want the same 5 rows it isn't exactly random anymore. But semantics aside maybe you need to store them in a temp table? The issue is that you haven't given enough of the requirements to provide a real answer.

Comment: Adding onto the "random but same" sentiment, the Church of XKCD has you covered - https://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RAND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql) function can have a seed as parameter.

But the resulting "random" float is predictable.
F.e.

```
select ID from table1 order by rand(ID)
```

would give the same order as

```
select ID from table1 order by ID
```

So the seeds need to be spiced up.
For example by a calculating a hash.

> ```
> declare @seed int = 42;
> select top 5 *
> from your_table
> order by rand(HashBytes('MD5', concat(col1, @seed)));
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>  id | col1
> --: | ---:
> 164 |   64
> 200 |  100
> 188 |   88
> 150 |   50
> 106 |    6
> ```

> ```
> declare @seed int = 42;
> select top 5 *
> from your_table
> order by rand(HashBytes('MD5', concat(col1, @seed)));
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>  id | col1
> --: | ---:
> 164 |   64
> 200 |  100
> 188 |   88
> 150 |   50
> 106 |    6
> ```

> ```
> declare @seed int = 43;
>
> select top 5 *
> from your_table
> order by rand(HashBytes('MD5', concat(col1, @seed)));
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>  id | col1
> --: | ---:
> 111 |   11
> 112 |   12
> 117 |   17
> 180 |   80
> 150 |   50
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0744dcde916819cbb39b757213493b13)*

Comment: Thank you very much! You understood the problem! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Thanks, you gave quite the peculiar problem.